# Users table in Postgres DB not synced while using LDAP in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: postgresql, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, openldap, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am trying to register users, client and peers in Hyperledger Fabric network using Postgres as database and using LDAP for authentication.

Although I'm able to generate certificates successfully and everything is working well but still while i check into the Postgres database then the **users** table is empty and there is no entry in that table, while **certificates** table is propagated properly and have all the certificates that I have generated.

I have checked postgres database **without integrating it with LDAP** and then the users table is updating successfully and I can see user entries there.

Is it a normal behavior or I'm missing something?